# Waiting for loop to execute and getting a value in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node Js programming. I know that javascript is not sequential and executes the code synchronously. I have been having a hard time getting my head around async calls.
Here is my problem:

in my `app.get('/send_friend_request', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {}`

I am trying to run a loop and get the value of counter, it will use this value to further choose if the person has already sent the request or not. I am basically checking if the user_id and from_id combinations already exist in FriendReq Collection in MongoDB:

```
var counter = 0;
    Profile.findOne({user_id: add_id}).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.friends_req.length; i++) {
                 FriendReq.findOne({_id: result.friends_req[i]}, function (err, res) {

                     if (res.user_id == add_id && res.from_id == id.toString()) {
                         counter = counter + 1
                     }
                     console.log("this is inside");
                     console.log(counter);  <---- this prints 1 but executes later
                 });
             }
console.log("this is outside");console.log(counter); <---- this prints 0
```

the problem is "this is outside" gets executed first. I have tried using async library but could not get it right:

```
 async.forEach(result.friends_req, function(item, callback){
            // call this callback when any asynchronous processing is done and
            // this iteration of the loop can be considered complete
            FriendReq.findOne({_id: item}, function (err, res) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.user_id + "===" + add_id + "," + res.from_id + "===" + id);
                if (res.user_id == add_id && res.from_id == id.toString()) {
                    counter = counter + 1
                }
                console.log("this is inside");

                console.log(counter);
            });
            callback();
            // function to run after loop has completed
        }, function(err) {
            if ( !err) console.log("final"+counter);
        });
```

Using this also "final" counter gets printed first. Can someone help me to get this right. My brain hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a count *pending* results, and when that count reaches zero you'll know your data retrieval is complete:

```
var counter = 0;
Profile.findOne({user_id: add_id}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    var pending = result.friends_req.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.friends_req.length; i++) {
        FriendReq.findOne({_id: result.friends_req[i]}, function (err, res) {
            if (res.user_id == add_id && res.from_id == id.toString()) {
                counter = counter + 1
            }
            console.log("this is inside");
            console.log(counter);
            if (!--pending) {
                // all done. Do what you want here: e.g. invoke a callback
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could look into promises. With mongoose `exec` you get a promise:

```
var counter = 0, promises;
Profile.findOne({user_id: add_id}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    promises = result.friends_req.map(function (friends_req) {
        return FriendReq.findOne({_id: friends_req}, function (err, res) {
            if (res.user_id == add_id && res.from_id == id.toString()) {
                counter = counter + 1
            }
        }).exec();
    };
}).then(function () {
    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
            console.log("all done");
            console.log(counter);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, i added
if (i === result.friends_req.length){
//do stuff}

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Just note that that only works if you are sure the callbacks are executed in the same order as you execute the `findOne` calls. In theory there is no guarantee for that. Also, `i` never becomes that value *within* the loop, so you need to compare with `length-1`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I got my code to work with option 2 using promises. Thanks a tonne.